# Multiple downloads in spring mvc, in this it only download first file and skip other files

Tags: spring-mvc

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/download-answer1-{userId}" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)

public String downloadAnswers1(@PathVariable int userId, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    try {
        String []docId1 = request.getParameterValues("doc-id");

        for(String docId : docId1) {
            UserDocument document = userDocumentService.findById(Integer.valueOf(docId));
            response.setContentType(document.getType());
            response.setContentLength(document.getContent().length);
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + document.getName() +"\"");

            FileCopyUtils.copy(document.getContent(), response.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("call me");
            response.flushBuffer();*/


        }
    }catch(Exception e) {}
    return "redirect:/download-answer-"+userId;
}
```

View  (downloadAnswer.jsp):

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/download-answer1-${userId}" method="post">
        <div class="panel-heading"><span class="lead">List of Documents </span><%-- <a href="<c:url value='/download-answer1-${user.id}-${doc.id}' />" class="btn btn-success custom-width" id="all"> --%><button onclick="return confirm('Are you sure')">download</button><!-- </a> --></div>

            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" class="slctDlt" ><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" ></th>
                        <th>No.</th>
                        <th>File Name</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th width="100"></th>
                        <th width="100"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${documents}" var="doc" varStatus="counter">
                    <tr id=''>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="dltCheck" name="doc-id" value="${doc.id}"></td>
                        <td>${counter.index + 1}</td>
                        <td>${doc.name}</td>
                        <td>${doc.type}</td>
                        <td>${doc.description}</td>
                        <td><a href="<c:url value='/download-answer1-${user.id}-${doc.id}' />" class="btn btn-success custom-width" >download</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
           </form>
```

I have already done lot of thing but all time it's download one files at time i.e. first file.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP protocol doesn't support responding with multiple files. It is not possible to perform this. If you need to iterate, the view would have to request multiple times and probably your controller servlet would have to be stateful for you to keep the iteration index.